# Shifting matrix along edges

Tags: java

I have this 2D array:

```java
this.matrix = new int[][] {
        {2, 3, 2},
        {1, 0, 1},
        {1, 1, 1}
};
```

**Leading spot: `[0][1] (always number 3)`**

I pick random element from the array, except the middle one (always zero).

Picked element: `[2][0]`

I'd like to shift elements so that the leading spot will be on picked element.

```
{1, 1, 1},
{2, 0, 1},
{3, 2, 1}
```

How can I do that? Is there some shift matrix what I can use?

Answer (score 1):

Here you are.

Since this answer is almost identical to that you've removed just prior to this one, I post my answer to it.

Working code: https://onlinegdb.com/HyWQCKWuO

This is how to use it.

To give an example, you have some matrix like as follows

```
0.14 0.22 0.14
0.1  0.0  0.1
0.1  0.1  0.1
```

Since specifying an index of a multidimensional array is somewhat complicated, I made a parseable string to serve as as in input.

Say, you want to rotate it taking the largest element as a start point.

Your matrix looks as follows:

```
[0][0] [0][1] [0][2]
[1][0] [1][1] [1][2]
[2][0] [2][1] [2][2]
```

So, to give a new position of a largest element you can specify:

```
pickedElementDimIndex = "21";
move(matrix);
```

Here is how your matrix will look:

```
0.1  0.1  0.1
0.1  0.0  0.1
0.14 0.22 0.14
```

If you input this command, your matrix will look as follows:

```
pickedElementDimIndex = "10";
move(matrix);

0.14 0.1  0.1
0.22 0.0  0.1
0.14 0.1  0.1
```

---

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Enum;
import java.lang.*;


public class Main {
    static boolean rotation = false;
    static String pickedElementDimIndex;
    static LinkedList < Double > link;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][] matrix = new double[][] {
            { 0.14, 0.22, 0.14 },
            { 0.10, 0.00, 0.10 },
            { 0.10, 0.10, 0.10 }
        };

        pickedElementDimIndex = "10";
        move(matrix);
    }

    public static void move(double[][] matrix) {
        String random = ClockwisePositionOfMaximalDouble.random().getValue();
        String dimIndexOfMaxElement = findOldDimIndexOfMaxDoubleButCentral(matrix);

        if (random == dimIndexOfMaxElement) {
            rotation = false;
        } else {
            rotation = true;
        }

        if (!rotation)
            return;

        int maxElementPos = getClockwisePosByDimIndex(dimIndexOfMaxElement);
        int pickedElementPos = getClockwisePosByDimIndex(pickedElementDimIndex);
        int distance = Math.abs(pickedElementPos - maxElementPos);
        if (maxElementPos > pickedElementPos)
            {distance = Math.abs(8 - distance);}

        System.out.println("pickedElementPos" + pickedElementPos);

        System.out.println("Distance" + distance);

        rotateMatrix(matrix, distance);
    }

    enum ClockwisePositionOfMaximalDouble {
        zeroth("00"),
            first("01"),
            second("02"),
            third("12"),
            fourth("22"),
            fifth("21"),
            sixth("20"),
            seventh("10");

        private static final List < ClockwisePositionOfMaximalDouble > VALUES =
            Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(values()));
        private static final int SIZE = VALUES.size();
        private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

        public static ClockwisePositionOfMaximalDouble random() {
            return VALUES.get(RANDOM.nextInt(SIZE));
        }

        private String code;

        private ClockwisePositionOfMaximalDouble(String code) {
            this.code = code;
        }

        public String getValue() {
            return code;
        }

    }

    static int getClockwisePosByDimIndex(String dimIndex) {
        switch (dimIndex) {
            case "00":
                return 0;
            case "01":
                return 1;
            case "02":
                return 2;
            case "12":
                return 3;
            case "22":
                return 4;
            case "21":
                return 5;
            case "20":
                return 6;
            case "10":
                return 7;
            default:
                throw new ArithmeticException("wrong dimIndex");
        }
    }

    static String findOldDimIndexOfMaxDoubleButCentral(double[][] elements) {
        double max = elements[0][0];
        int maxI = 0;
        int maxJ = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < elements[i].length; j++) {
                if (i == 1 & j == 1)
                    continue;
                if (elements[i][j] > max) {
                    max = elements[i][j];
                    maxI = i;
                    maxJ = j;
                }
            }
        }
        return "" + maxI + maxJ;
    }

    static void rotateMatrix(double[][] matrix, int newClockwisePos) {

        printMatrix(matrix);

        link = new LinkedList < Double > ();

        link.add(matrix[0][0]);
        link.add(matrix[0][1]);
        link.add(matrix[0][2]);
        link.add(matrix[1][2]);
        link.add(matrix[2][2]);
        link.add(matrix[2][1]);
        link.add(matrix[2][0]);
        link.add(matrix[1][0]);

        for (int i = 0; i < newClockwisePos; i++) {
            double removedLast = link.removeLast();
            link.addFirst(removedLast);
        }
        matrix[0][0] = link.get(0);
        matrix[0][1] = link.get(1);
        matrix[0][2] = link.get(2);
        matrix[1][2] = link.get(3);
        matrix[2][2] = link.get(4);
        matrix[2][1] = link.get(5);
        matrix[2][0] = link.get(6);
        matrix[1][0] = link.get(7);

        printMatrix(matrix);

    }

    static void printMatrix(double[][] matrix) {
        for (double[] x: matrix) {
            for (double y: x) {
                System.out.print(y + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: There was a bug in my initial answer. One need to add `if (maxElementPos>pickedElementPos) {distance = Math.abs(8 - distance);}` right after `int distance = Math.abs(pickedElementPos - maxElementPos);` to take into account the cases where pickedElementPos < maxElementPos